# Shopify Schema Select Value

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

I'm trying to access the selected schema value in Shopify and all that gets returned is the label formatted in lowercase with dashes instead of spaces.

`

```
{
        "type": "hmc360_options",
        "name": "3D Configuration Options",
        "settings": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "options_title",
            "label": "Title",
            "default": "3D Options"
          },
          {
            "type": "select",
            "id": "hmc360-option-type",
            "label": "Option Type",
            "default": "na",
            "options": [
              {
                "label": "Style",
                "value": "pick_a_style"
              },
              {
                "value": "pick_a_wood_finish",
                "label": "Finish"
              },
              {
                "label": "N/A",
                "value": "na"
              }
            ]
          }
}
```

When {{ block.settings.hmc360-option-type }} is used in Liquid, it returns the value as described above. I can't seem to find anything about this so I'm lead to believe it's something silly on my end.

{{ block.settings.hmc360-option-type }} should return "pick_a_style" or "pick_a_wood_finish"

Comment: What you currently get when print it into liquid

Answer (score 0):

from your code, it should return the value `na` because by default you choose `na`, you can make a condition to return the value you want

```
{% liquid
  assign s = section.settings

  if s.hmc360-option-type == 'pick_a_style'
    assign options = 'Style'
  elsif s.hmc360-option-type == 'pick_a_wood_finish'
    assign options = 'Finish'
  else
    assign options = 'NA'
  endif

%}

{% options %}
```